# Using scons to perform validation

Tags: python, scons

My company is switching from make to scons.  Part of our make process is to call xmllint on a number of xml files to validate them against a schema.

I've got the following in my SConstruct:

```
import os;
Env = DefaultEnvironment()
pwd = Dir('.').path
xmlValidator = Builder(action = 'xmllint --noout  --schema '+pwd+'/path/schema.xsd '+pwd+'file.xml')
Env.Append(BUILDERS = {'ValidateXML' : xmlValidator})
Env.ValidateXML()
```

When I run:

```
scons -Q
```

I get:

```
scons: `.' is up to date.
```

But no validation is run.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm completely new to scons, and moderately familiar with Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide scons with an input file. You currently have the source file hard-coded into the builder "recipe". It is better to use the SOURCE placeholder in the action string and then specify the input file when you call the builder.

```
xmlValidator = Builder(action='xmllint --noout --schema '+
                               pwd+'/path/schema.xsd $SOURCE')
Env.Append(BUILDERS = {'ValidateXML' : xmlValidator})
Env.ValidateXML(source='file.xml')
```

This will always run the validation, so you might want to have it output the result to a file. To do that you would use the TARGET placeholder, for example:

```
xmlValidator = Builder(action='xmllint --schema '+
                       pwd+'/path/schema.xsd $SOURCE --output $TARGET')
Env.ValidateXML(source='file.xml', target="out.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  This worked perfectly except the --noout switch has to be dropped when using the --output switch in the second example.

Comment: OK, good to know. I've edited the example so it makes sense, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you also use the XML files as input to some other builder. By using a builder with multiple actions you could perform the validation at that stage instead. Something like this:

```
xslt = Builder(action=['xmllint --noout --schema /path/to/schema.xsd $SOURCE',
                       'xsltproc --output $TARGET /path/to/style.xsl $SOURCE'])
Env.Append(BUILDERS = {'XSLT' : xslt})
```

With this solution there is no need to create any unnecessary files. If the XML files are generated you could similarly create a builder that both generates the file and perform the validation.